# Is it possible to get less variables after Lagrange's method for quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

For example, I have a quadratic form $ F = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 4x_3^2 + x_4^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 4x_1x_3 - 2x_1x_4 + 4x_2x_3 - 6x_2x_4 $. 
After applying Lagrange's method of reduction to canonical form I get a result of $ y_1^2 - y_2^2 + y^3 $.
Is this even possible in this case? How could the number of variables be lowered?

Comment: Sure. The quadric is degenerate. Check the determinant of the related symmetric matrix.

Comment: @amd Isn't the transformation matrix going to be non-quadratic with dimensions 4x3?

Comment: No. One of the terms in the transformed form has a coefficient of $0$.

Comment: @amd I don't get it. In that case, the determinant of that matrix will be 0 which contradicts the rule of transformation. Or this is simpler?

Comment: The determinant of the transformed form will be $0$, not the determinant of the transformation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

look up Sylvester's Law of Inertia. Here is a method that is largely the reverse order of Lagrange's. Results first

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==========================================

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
2 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 2 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can happen, but it is only possible when rank of the quadratic form is smaller than the number of variables that occur; thus, a minimal example occurs in dimension $2$.

For example, in the coordinates defined by the linear change of coordinates $$y_1 = x_1 + x_2, \qquad y_2 = x_2,$$ the quadratic form $$Q({\bf x}) := x_1^2 + 2 x_1 x_2 + x_2^2$$
is
$$Q({\bf y}) = y_1^2 ,$$
which has rank $1$.

At least in case that the underlying field is algebraically closed, the minimum number of variables that can occur in the expression is the rank of the form; Sylvester's Law of Inertia implies that the same is true over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Actually, a minimal example occurs in dimension $1$: the quadratic form $0$.

Comment: By "the number of variables that occur" I don't mean the dimension of the underlying vector space. Since OP did not refer to a dimension, I took his meaning to be (and by "the number of variables that occur") I meant the number of variables that literally appear in the standard form of the quadratic form w.r.t. some linear coordinates $x^i$, or put another way, the number of nonzero coefficients $a_{ij}$ in the expression $\sum_{i \leq j} a_{ij} x^i x^j$. In this sense, of course $0$ variables occur the expression of the quadratic form $0$, in particular w.r.t. any linear coordinates.